# How to bulk copy the values from a TSQLQuery record to a TdxMemData record?

Tags: sql, delphi, devexpress

Just to make it clear, I do not want to copy the entire TSQLQuery into the TdxMemData, as I would use memds.CopyFromDataSet(qry) for that.

I am interating through each record from the TSQLQuery, and I may or may not be adding a record(s) to the TdxMemData. Generally the record in memds matches that in qry, but sometimes the values are altered and sometimes additional records are added to memds. My example did not make this clear since all it seemed to do was copy over each record.

So given an active record in the TSQLQuery, I want to copy over the values into an active editable record in the TdxMemData.

The following code works in so far as it creates a copy of the record:

```
qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
memds := TdxMemData.Create(nil);

try
  qry.SQLConnection := cn;
  qry.Text := 'SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Table1';
  qry.Open
  
  memds.CreateFieldsFromDataSet(qry);
  memds.Open;

  while not qry.Eof do
  begin
    if {some condition} then
    begin
      memds.Append;
      
      for i := 0 to qry.FieldCount-1 do
        memds.Fields[i+1].Value := qry.Fields[i].Value; //First field is RecID
    
      //Do something with the current memds record
    end
    else if {some other condition} then
    begin
      memds.Append;
      //change values
      memds.Append;
      //change values
      memds.Append;
      //change values
    end
    else if {a third condition} then
      ; //Skip any work on memds
    qry.next;
  end;
  
  qry.Close;
  
  //Do something with memds
  
  memds.Close;
finally
  memds.Free;
  qry.Free;
end;
```

Is there a better way? I had looked at AppendRecord but creating the array of TVarRec doesn't seem to be straightforward.

EDIT:

Let's use these examples with very simplified criteria. Note that the actual conditions that determine how many records to append and the changes to the field values in the destination are complex and not in any database.

Method 1:

```
While not tblSource.Eof do
Begin
  If (iCondition = 1) Then
  Begin
    // Add one record

    tblDestination.Append;

    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field1').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field1').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field2').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field2').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field3').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field3').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field4').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field4').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field5').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field5').Value; 

    if bSomethingCondition then
      tblDestination.FieldByName('Field4').Value := 'Something';
  End
  Else If (iCondition = 2) Then
  Begin
    // Add two records

    tblDestination.Append;

    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field1').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field1').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field2').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field2').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field3').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field3').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field4').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field4').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field5').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field5').Value; 

    if bAnotherThingCondition then
      tblDestination.FieldByName('Field4').Value := 'Another thing'; 

    tblDestination.Append;

    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field1').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field1').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field2').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field2').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field3').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field3').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field4').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field4').Value; 
    tblDestination.FieldByName('Field5').Value := tblSource.FieldByName('Field5').Value; 

    if bSomethingElseCondition then
      tblDestination.FieldByName('Field4').Value := 'Something else'; 
  End
  Else If (iCondition = 0) Then
  Begin
    // Add no records
  End;

  tblSource.Next;
End;
```

Since the number of fields in the source and destination tables can vary, hard-coding field names as in Method 1 is not suitable.

Method 2:

```
While not tblSource.Eof do
Begin
  If (iCondition = 1) Then
  Begin
    // Add one record

    tblDestination.Append;

    for i := 0 to tblSource.FieldCount-1 do
      tblDestination.Fields[i+1].Value := tblSource.Fields[i].Value;

    if bSomethingCondition then
      tblDestination.Fields(iSomethingConditionFieldIndex).Value := 'Something';
  End
  Else If (iCondition = 2) Then
  Begin
    // Add two records

    tblDestination.Append;

    for i := 0 to tblSource.FieldCount-1 do
      tblDestination.Fields[i+1].Value := tblSource.Fields[i].Value;

    if bAnotherThingCondition then
      tblDestination.Fields(iAnotherThingConditionFieldINdex).Value := 'Another thing'; 

    tblDestination.Append;

    for i := 0 to tblSource.FieldCount-1 do
      tblDestination.Fields[i+1].Value := tblSource.Fields[i].Value;

    if bSomethingElseCondition then
      tblDestination.Fields(iSomethingElseConditionFieldIndex).Value := 'Something else'; 
  End
  Else If (iCondition = 0) Then
  Begin
    // Add no records
  End;

  tblSource.Next;
End;
```

While method 2 above does work, and is the way it is currently done, this question is whether there is a way to pass the variant array of field values from tblSource to tblDestination using AppendRecord.

Instead of this:

```
// Add one record

tblDestination.Append;

for i := 0 to tblSource.FieldCount-1 do
   tblDestination.Fields[i+1].Value := tblSource.Fields[i].Value;

if bSomethingCondition then
  tblDestination.Fields(iSomethingConditionFieldIndex).Value := 'Something';
```

Do this:

```
tblDestination.AppendRecord({tblSource fields var array);

if bSomethingCondition then
  tblDestination.Fields(iSomethingConditionFieldIndex).Value := 'Something';
```

Of course, it might be that there is no answer, and that the method I currently employ is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
  Query1.Open();
  dxMemData1.AddFieldsFromDataSet(Query1);
  dxMemData1.Open;
  dxMemData1.LoadFromDataSet(Query1);
```

Comment: If I wanted to copy the whole dataset, yes, I could do that, or just use memds.CopyDataSet(qry). What I want is to copy a single record.

Comment: If you were using FireDac's TFDMemTable, then you could use CopyRecord which copies a single record.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of `TVarRec` isn't difficult, and `AppendRecord` may indeed help. The following code adds a record to a `TClientDataSet` (named `CDS` for brevity) that has 4 fields of type string, float, boolean, and string in that order:

```
CDS.AppendRecord(['Smith', 123.45, False, 'Test text']);
```

Note that you have to create a value for every single field (column) in the dataset, in the order that they exist in the `FieldDefs` collection, or you'll get an exception.

(Of course, the real question is why you're returning extra rows and iterating through them, instead of testing the conditions in your SQL statement `WHERE` clause and only returning the rows you actually need. This can almost always be done using parameters.)

Comment: The conditions that are being checked as to whether 1 record, 3 records or no records are to be added to the destination table for each record in the source table are too complex for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use AddFieldsFromDataSet -> LoadFromDataSet , and want to load fields and records manually, you also can do it. You can create fields programmatically and append records by iterations. Look example:

```
MD.Fields.Clear;
MD.FieldDefs.Clear;
MD.Close;

with MD.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
begin
  Name := 'UserID';
  DataType := TFieldType.ftInteger;
  CreateField(MD);
  Name := 'GridName';
  DataType := TFieldType.ftString;
  Size := 255;
  CreateField(MD);
  Name := 'TemplateGrid';
  DataType := TFieldType.ftBlob;
  CreateField(MD);
end;

MD.Close;
MD.Open;

MD.Append;

MD.FieldByName('UserID').AsInteger := 1;
MD.FieldByName('GridName').AsString := Self.Name
TBlobField(MD.FieldByName('TemplateGrid')).LoadFromStream(LStream);
MD.Post;
```

You can easily modify it to load fields with names and types from your dataset as they are.

Comment: Yes. I can easily do destination.field1 = source.field1, destination.field2 = source.field2, etc., and that is what I do now, but I had hoped for a way I didn't need to specify each field separately. I'll edit my question to indicate the way I would have liked it.